# NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I work with unit test in Rails..,
Here is my code located in test\unit\sample_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'test/unit'
require 'sample'

class SampleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "student details" do
        student = Student.new
        student.Date_of_joining = DateTime.now
        student.id = "123"
     assert_student student 
   end
end
```

And my app\models\sample.rb contains the following..,

```
class Sample     
  def assert_student(student)
        #assert_equal "123", student.external_reference
        "#{student_id}"
   end
end
```

when i am running "rake test:units" it shows an following error

```
 test_student_details(SampleTest):
    NameError: uninitialized constant SampleTest::Student
        test/unit/sample_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:SampleTest>'
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to require the file where your SampleTest::Student is to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Rails should take care of loading your models for you in `test_helper`, so you don't need to explicitly require 'sample'. Where is the `Student` class defined?

Files in lib/ are not autoloaded by default in Rails 3.x so you'd need to explicitly require 'student' in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `::` global scope accessor like so:

```
student = ::Student.new
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are instantiating a Student object inside the Sample unit test.  Is that deliberate or a typo?

The answer to your question depends on the details and location of the ActiveRecord::Student class implementation, as @Jesse Stormier mentioned.